# static files in django 1.6 not found

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles, django-1.6

I'm just starting with django 1.6 and my css is not working neither my images, I get a 404 error, even the admin(s css is not working

Here is my file structure :

```
myproject
--myproject
----templates
--static
----css
----media
--myapp
--mp.db
--manage.py
```

This is my base.html :

```
<link rel="image_src" href="{% block image_src %}http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}/static/images/logo.png{% endblock %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/utils.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/{% block style_link %}style{% endblock %}.css">
   ...
<div id="cont_footer" class="container centerAuto">
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/logo_footer.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

This is my settings :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname( __file__ )
PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(PROJECT_ROOT)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL +'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
```

In urls.py  :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name="index"),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

What am I doing wrong?I'm pulling my hair off because of this since three days now!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make folder "static" in root of your project where settings.py exists

In settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'template'),
)
```

In base.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/demo.css' %}" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

In other template files in which you include base.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>


<div id="yourID" class="yourClass">
    <img src="{% static "images/something.gif" %}" alt="something" >
</div>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from wepl.views import home
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from myApp import settings
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'myApp.views.home', name='home'),

    )

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: my static folder is in root as I mentioned in my question , I did the changes you suggested but it still not working! what am I doing wrong?I'm pulling my hair off because of this since two days nos!!