# Cannot serve static files, Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, static

I am unable to get Django 1.6 to serve static files.

In my settings.py I have:

```
DEBUG = True

#...

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #...
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/it/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
)
STATIC_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

I have also added the following to my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The HTML file in question has the following:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
#...
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}' />
```

The relevant parts of the project tree look like this:

```
/media/extra/django/
├── it
│   ├── it
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── jobs
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── base.css
│   │   └── colours.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── favicon.ico
│   └── scripts
│       └── base.js
└── templates
    ├── it
    │   ├── base.html
    │   └── index.html
    ├── jobs
    │   └── index.html
    ├── site_base.html
```

I have tried having the static directory as a sibling of the 'it' directory (and changing the STATIC_DIRS variable).  I have tried using += staticfiles_urlpatterns() on the urlpatterns instead.  I have tried adding the full path to the STATIC_DIRS.

I have also looked at these relevant threads:
[static files in django 1.6 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425129/static-files-in-django-1-6-not-found)
[Can't get Django to serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463205/cant-get-django-to-serve-static-files)
[Django 1.6.2 will not serve static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062254/django-1-6-2-will-not-serve-static-content)

Many thanks

Comment: The setting is `DEBUG`, not `Debug`. Django will not serve static content if DEBUG is not True.

Comment: i don't see no STATIC_ROOT in the settings, but you are calling that in your urls.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman typo, in the file it is 'DEBUG'

Comment: @drabo2005 it was omitted from the paste here - I'll edit the question

Comment: What if you change the value of STATIC_ROOT to `'/media/extra/django/static/'`?

Comment: @GP89 Still getting 404s; added that path to STATIC_DIRS too

Comment: Check everything in your project matches what you have here (it should be working now I think)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your setup, but this are the settings that work for me:

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'),
    )
```

I haven't defined STATIC_ROOT or STATIC_FINDERS so it's using the defaults. I have nothing special in urls.py for static files, just one line for media:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The static tag is working fine from the templates so I believe your line in `urls.py` is not absolutely needed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be serving static content through a web framework, that's a job for the webserver (apache or nginx for example)

If you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your settings.py file you can put `"{{ STATIC_URL }}css/base.css"` in your templates for example, and have the web server serve `/static/` statically, bypassing django completely.

Comment: This is for development only: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: @bcvery1 Ah ok - I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py  try to tell django standard views to serve your static files by changing 
    the urlpatterns

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
   #...
 ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

 With the following:

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
   #...
 )
 if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += patterns('',
   (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
   {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),)


 In the settings.py add:

 import os.path
 STATIC_ROOT ='only_the_path_to_the_project'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'staticcc').replace('\\','/'),
  )
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what the static function does that was already there

Comment: may be it the BASE_DIRS path the problem , do you mean STATICFILES_DIRS by STATIC_DIRS

Answer (score 0):

**In development**
In your app folder create folder name 'static' and save your picture in that folder.

To use picture use:

```
<html>
    <head>
       {% load staticfiles %} <!-- Prepare django to load static files -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src={% static "image.jpg" %}>
    </body>
</html>
```

**In production:**
Everything same like in development, just add couple more parameters for Django:
1. add in **settings.py**
 `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")`(this will prepare folder where static files from all apps will be stored)

2. be sure your app is in `INSTALLED_APPS = ['myapp',]`

3. in terminall run command **python manage.py collectstatic** (this will make copy of static files from all apps included in INSTALLED_APPS to global static folder - STATIC_ROOT folder )

Thats all what Django need, after this you need to make some web server side setup to make premissions for use static folder. E.g. in apache2 in configuration file **httpd.conf** (for windows) or **sites-enabled/000-default.conf.** (under site virtual host part for linux) add:

```
 Alias \static "path_to_your_project\static"

<Directory "path_to_your_project\static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And that's all